# How to Resizing Controls of form with Form resize

Tags: powershell

in this video explain how resize a form with .net, i woul like to know, how do that in powershell, someone can add the necessary code to my example ?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVi1ve5qHXA

i try to use dock or achor, but nothig.

The result I would like to achieve is exactly what you see in the video, the video has been inserted to clarify what I intend to do.
Each object in the form: buttons, listbox, ouputbox and so on must be resized when I drag the right corner of the form, or when I use the standard button in the "Maximize" window.

```
CLS

$width = 1120
$Height = 560

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form    
$form.AutoSize = $true
$Form.MaximizeBox = $true
$form.ClientSize.Width = 2240
$form.ClientSize.Height = 1120
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$imagelistPC = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.ImageList'
$listviewPC = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$listviewPC.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,125) 
$listviewPC.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(585,180) 
$form.Controls.Add($listviewPC) 

$button1user = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$button1user.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(625,30) 
$button1user.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,40)
$button1user.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$button1user.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif', 7, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$button1user.Text = "test1" 
$button1user.BackColor = "Yellow"
$button1user.Add_Click({test1}) 
$button1user.AutoSize = $true
$Form.Controls.Add($button1user)  

$button2user = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$button2user.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(625,80)
$button2user.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,40)
$button2user.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$button2user.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif', 7, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$button2user.Text = "test2" 
$button2user.BackColor = "Yellow"
$button2user.Add_Click({test2}) 
$Form.Controls.Add($button2user)  

$button3user = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$button3user.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(625,130) 
$button3user.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,40)
$button3user.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$button3user.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif', 7, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$button3user.Text = "test3" 
$button3user.BackColor = "Yellow"
$button3user.Add_Click({test3})
$Form.Controls.Add($button3user) 

$button1pc = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$button1pc.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(745,30) 
$button1pc.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,40)
$button1pc.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$button1pc.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif', 7, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$button1pc.Text = "test A" 
$button1pc.BackColor = "Yellow"
$button1pc.Add_Click({COMPUTERCHANGEOU}) 
$Form.Controls.Add($button1pc)  

$button2pc = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$button2pc.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(745,80) 
$button2pc.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,40)
$button2pc.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$button2pc.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif', 7, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$button2pc.Text = "test B" 
$button2pc.BackColor = "Yellow"
$button2pc.Add_Click({b}) 
$Form.Controls.Add($button2pc) 

$button3pc = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$button3pc.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(745,130) 
$button3pc.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,40)
$button3pc.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$button3pc.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif', 7, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$button3pc.Text = "test C" 
$button3pc.BackColor = "Yellow"
$button3pc.Add_Click({c}) 
$Form.Controls.Add($button3pc) 

$outputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$outputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,320) 
$outputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(585,180) 
$outputBox.MultiLine = $True 
$outputBox.ReadOnly = $True
$outputBox.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Calibri",11,[System.drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$outputBox.ForeColor = [Drawing.Color]::Green
$outputBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical" 
$Form.Controls.Add($outputBox) 

$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
[void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 1):

I won't write the code for you because it'll take a lot of time and effort, but I can give you an example.

First let's make some form elements and anchor them:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize = '500,230'
$Form.text = "Some title"
$Form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$Button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,150)
$Button1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$Button1.Text = "START"
$Button1.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Top `
-bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Bottom `
-bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Left `
-bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Right

$ListBox1 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$ListBox1.text = "listBox"
$ListBox1.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50,50)
$ListBox1.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,50)
$ListBox1.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Top `
-bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Bottom `
-bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Left `
-bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Right

$form.Controls.AddRange(@($Button1, $ListBox1))
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

As you can see right now, the elements are resizing. Try to comment out top and bottom anchor and see what is going to happen.

However this solution has a big fault. If you are going to resize them too much, elements will start to overlap. You can resolve this problem by using (for example) [Panel Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.panel?view=netframework-4.8), so we can create different kinds of layouts. I'm gonna show you some sample code with [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel?view=netframework-4.8):

```
$tableLayoutPanel1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel
$tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 2 #how many rows
$tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2 #how many columns
$tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add($Button1, 0, 0) #choose where to place button
$tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add($ListBox1, 1, 1) #choose where to place listbox
$tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill #choose style

#make rows the same size
$tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add((new-object System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle([System.Windows.Forms.SizeType]::Percent, 50)))
$tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add((new-object System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle([System.Windows.Forms.SizeType]::Percent, 50)))
#make columns the same size
$tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add((new-object System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle([System.Windows.Forms.SizeType]::Percent,50)))
$tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add((new-object System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle([System.Windows.Forms.SizeType]::Percent,50)))

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($tableLayoutPanel1)) #don't add button and listbox here because they're already added by tablelayoutpanel
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

If you want to merge columns or rows you can try:

```
$tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan($Button1,2)
```

or:

```
$tableLayoutPanel1.SetRowSpan($Button1,2)
```

Additional note: you can delete lines with form elements size and location value because they wont'matter if you're using `TableLayoutPanel`. You can find working code of my example [here](https://pastebin.com/PjtJ1bgm).

Comment: I can't set the correct position of each button, if you look at my example I have two columns of buttons at a certain height, if I apply the "dock :: fill" method the buttons are resized saturating the size of the form, if I put "dock" :: right "I can't set the correct height. This is why I asked you to start from my example.

Answer (score 0):

As per your video. You are resizing the individual embedded form element on the form panel in designer mode, not a running application.

This is what drag and drop designer allow for. There is no built-in drang a drop designer for PowerShell. There is an extension for VSCode that you can buy from the VSCode MarketPlace, [PowerShell Pro Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ironmansoftware.powershellprotools)  , or use [PoshGui](https://poshgui.com/Editor?Tab=1) and save and use / retool the code from there.

You seem to be saying that you want a user to be able to resize those button or other objects on a running application. Correct me if I am incorrect here, yet, if that's the case, then that's not really a thing, I've ever seen in any app, using any language. Also, I am not sure what use case (resizing from elements at runtime) that would solve.

Resizing the form and having the elements auto resize based on form size, sure, which is what nemze is showing.